# How to move HBase tables to HDFS in Parquet format?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, parquet, hfile

I have to build a tool which will process our data storage from HBase(HFiles) to HDFS in parquet format.

Please suggest one of the best way to move data from HBase tables to Parquet tables.

We have to move 400 million records from HBase to Parquet. How to achieve this and what is the fastest way to move data?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Pardeep Sharma.

Comment: "Parquet" you mean to say parquet avro ? Hbase is schema less where as parquet avro file has schema. what do you want to do with this data in parquet ? If you are using  binary/protobuf these are the complex data types may create some issues while creating parquet. please see  my answer.

Comment: Yes it's Parquet avro. In our next step we'll use these parquet files for testing. Thanks for your immediate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look in to this project [tmalaska/HBase-ToHDFS](https://github.com/tmalaska/HBase-ToHDFS/tree/master/src/main/java/com/cloudera/sa/hbase/to/hdfs) 
which reads a HBase table and writes the out as Text, Seq, Avro, or Parquet

#### Example usage for parquet :

[Exports the data to Parquet](https://github.com/tmalaska/HBase-ToHDFS#exports-the-data-to-parquet)

```
hadoop jar HBaseToHDFS.jar ExportHBaseTableToParquet exportTest c export.parquet false avro.schema
```

Comment: Hi @RamPrasad G, Can we do the same in spark.

Comment: yes off course. There is a project called spark on Hbase(http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/). I think you use same input formats. Im not sure please check

Comment: I see that the project has not been updated for 3 years. Can anyone confirm if it still works?

Comment: Spark on Hbase is not supported for Spark 2.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently opensourced a patch to HBase which tackles the problem you are describing.
Have a look here: https://github.com/ibm-research-ireland/hbaquet